# Setting the background color of statusbar in IOS app in XE8

Tags: delphi, background, firemonkey, statusbar, delphi-xe8

I want to set the background color (and foreground color) of the status bar in my freshly created Delphi XE8 Firemonkey app. With the status bar I mean the top bar with the time and wifi widgets.

I just cannot find it. I need some help :-)

Thanks, 
Edward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Fill.Color of the form controls the color of the toolbar, and the average luminance of this color controls wether the text is white or black**

Borderstyle must be <> None, or else the toolbar will be hidden.

If you have multiple forms, it is a bit unclear what form is used, but it seems like it is the last form being auto-created in your project file.

Here is some relevant sourcecode from `FMX.Platform.iOS.pas` that documents the color of the text:

```
procedure TPlatformCocoaTouch.UpdateStatusBarColor(const AForm: TCommonCustomForm);
  ...
  AppDelegate.MainWindow.RootViewController.SetStatusBarBackgroundColor((AForm as TCustomForm).Fill.Color);
  ...

procedure TFMXViewController.SetStatusBarBackgroundColor(const ABackgroundColor: TAlphaColor);
  ...
  FStatusBarLuminance := Luminance(ABackgroundColor);
  ...

function TFMXViewController.preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle;
begin
  if FStatusBarLuminance < 0.5 then
    Result := UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
  else
    Result := UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
end;
```

PS. I have another unanswered SO question about how to [make the statusbar transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043510/delphi-xe7-how-to-get-native-statusbar-behavior-in-ios-7), which is native iOS 7+ behavior.

Comment: About your question. I'm still a bit inexperienced with fmx so i'm afraid I cannot help you. If I find something I let you know. I would say that having to override or replace UIStatusBarStyleLightContent / UIStatusBarStyleDefault should do it. But you probably did this already.

Comment: The question is about making the statusbar transparent (where it currently show the background color), but my finding so far is that it is not possible to control it when using Delphi (Delphi seem to override my attempts to set it manually)

Answer (score 0):

Recomendation from book "Cross-Platform Development with Delphi XE7 and FireMonkey for Windows & MAC OS X" by Harry Stahl

> TStatusbar (a way to compensate the missing “Panels”)
>
> In the VCL
> status bar you can display a text either on the property “Panels” or
> via the “SimpleText” property. In the FireMonkey status bar there is
> nothing of the sort, no text property. So you could use the status bar
> as container and there, for example, insert Labels .
>
> Better solution:
> Just take a TGrid! As you can see in the screenshot shown below, I
> have included in the StatusBar a TGrid. In the TGrid I have 2
> TStringColumns, a TImageColumn, again a TStringColumn and a
> TProgressColumn added. In the Objectinspector, I have set for the
> TGrid:

Comment: Hi this is not what I ment. Thanks anyway!